# How to install Tomcat container for Docker in Fedora 28?

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I am new in **Docker**, I would like to know how to install *Tomcat Container* from the command line, also, what are the pre-requisites, do I need to download **Java** on Fedora 28 first? Or Tomcat already contains a **JVM** ?

Comment: You need to install docker, after installing refer this  https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/,   docker pull tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`tomcat/8.5/jre8/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/5d36a1cb80ddf73f37353460a5b1eb0f7a675779/8.5/jre8/Dockerfile) image definition starts with

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
```

So it already includes a JDK.

All you need to do is run the default Tomcat server (CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]):

```
$ docker run -it --rm tomcat:8.0
```

You can test it by visiting http://container-ip:8080

See more at [`hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/`](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/).

All you need is to [install docker first](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/).

The OP adds:

> To be able to connect I had to run below command to get the container ID with
>
> ```
> docker ps
>  docker inspect <containerid> | grep "IPAddress"
> ```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I can't upvote since I'm low on the reputation. To be able to connect I had to run below command to get the container ID with `docker ps` then  `docker inspect <containerid> | grep "IPAddress"`

Comment: @JoseLuisSotoPosada Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.